# Font family shifted outside of container

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I am using a specific font-family. When changing elements to this family the text gets somehow shifted outside the box/container on multiple elements on my website.

I already treid to play with a lot of options like line-height, padding, margin, vertical-align etc. but without sucess.

How to get rid of this font-shifting?

Hope you will have some hints for me.

Best wishes, L

[Normal font without shifting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMn2.png)
[New font with shifting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwxh0.png)

Comment: Share your HTML CSS code without code u can't get an optimized solution to your problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "font-size" to something smaller?

Comment: No, there is no special css applied but there is a shift always on the bottom of each paragraph. Somehow this is the font-family where this is configured like this. On mac the problem is not there only on windows. It is the same in Firefox, Safari, Chrome...